# Return correctop devuelve undefined

Tags: nodejs, funciones, undefined, parametros, sequelize

Buenas tardes a todos y gracias por vuestra colaboración. Estoy desarrollando un backend en Nodejs con sequelize y postgreSQL. He creado un repositorio base para el CRUD de tablas y me pasa lo siguiente, tengo el siguiente método en dicho repositorio:

```
async get(id) {
    await this.model.findByPk(id)
        .then((entityFound) => {
            if (!entityFound) {
                generaError(404, 401);
            }
            return { status: 200, message: dameMensaje(400), data: entityFound.toJSON() }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            throw e; // generaError(500, 401, e.message);
        });
}
```

que se ejecuta correctamente y en entityFound introduce el registro encontrado, pues bien al hacer el return a la función de llamada:

```
async get(id) {
    if (!id) {
        return generaError(400, 301)
    }
    const entity = await this.repository.get(id);
    return entity
}
```

en la constante entity me devuelve  undefined. ¿Alquien me puede orientar en que está pasando?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Disculpad las molestias, pero a veces no hay nada como leer una pregunta propia para darse cuenta de las meteduras de pata. Obviamente me faltaba hacer el return de la devolución de la promesa, os pongo el codigo del repositorio ya cambiado:

```
async get(id) {
    return await this.model.findByPk(id)
        .then((entityFound) => {
            if (!entityFound) {
                generaError(404, 401);
            }
            return { status: 200, message: dameMensaje(400), data: entityFound.dataValues }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            throw e; // generaError(500, 401, e.message);
        });
}
```

Gracias a todos